# Como puedo acceder a mis archivos mediante una pila ingresada?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, pilas, visual

*Tengo que hacer un programa que mediante una pila ingresada, pueda crear la cadena o sea la ruta de acceso, pro solo puedo ingresar datos en la pila.*

```
Stack<String> PilaDireccion = new Stack<string>();
        void Agregar()
        {
            PilaDireccion.Push(txtNombre.Text);
            ibImprimir.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var item in PilaDireccion)
            {
                ibImprimir.Items.Add(item);
                ibImprimir.Items.Add("__________");             
            }
            txtNombre.Clear();
            txtNombre.Focus();
        }
        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            { Agregar(); }
        }
```

Necesito ayuda, soy estudiante.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes! Por favor, edita tu pregunta y cuéntanos qué problema tienes con el código que nos compartes. Entendemos el enunciado, pero aquí se trata de ayudarte a que tu código haga lo que quieres que haga y pues... no sabemos en qué falla :). Recuerda usar el enlace _editar_ que está justo debajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas para añadir esta información que te indiqué.

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el código no falla, pero no encuentro información de como hacer lo que me piden, solo puedo ingresar datos a la pila, pero no se como llegar de eso, a usarlo como cadena para hacer una ruta que acceda a mis archivos.

Comment: no entiendo el problema.. ya creaste la pila.. ya le agregas items a la pila.. cual seria el problema??

Comment: Que la pila que acabo de crear la tengo que usar para crear una ruta que me permita entrar a mis archivos

Comment: Hm, ok, la cosa es que indiques en tu pregunta, con datos de ejemplo, qué ingresarías en el programa, qué debería salir de lo que te falta hacer, cualquier cosa que hayas intentado (intentarlo siempre está bien, así falle!)